# Google Sheets: array Formula that sums between 2 cell references

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm having an issue creating a formula to dynamically sum values between 2 cell references.

I have the following data:

```
Name     |    Hours Worked     |
 John              20
         -----------------------
                   10
         -----------------------
                   8  
--------------------------------
 Stef              8
         -----------------------
                   10
--------------------------------
 Liiv              8
         -----------------------
                   10
         -----------------------
                   10
         -----------------------
                   8
```

What I want to do is to produce a report in another sheet like this

```
Name     |    Hours Worked     |
 John              38
 Stef              18
 Liiv              36
```

[Check out the sample file here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mga3sGKAbwLAisgbi7SOto8bZaUZyjdaPEmBW73g2h4/edit#gid=996538255)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try in D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(ROW(data!A8:A), 
 IF(data!A8:A<>"", {ROW(data!A8:A), data!A8:A}), 2, 1), "(.+)\n")), data!D8:D, 
 SUBSTITUTE(data!F8:F, "$", )*1}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)''", 0))
```

[image]